# Codename One HTML parsing

Tags: android, html-parsing, jsoup, codenameone

I am working on create an Iphone app. I need to display part of a web page on a laber on Codename One or the equivalent to a TextView on Android.

In Android I use JAVA jsoup

How can Implement this code on Codename One:

```
 Document  document = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0")
                    .get();

            Elements element1=document.select("#pd_foto_fondo > div:nth-child(2)");
            String string1=ultact.text();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) XML parser which can parse HTML as well and you can use the [processing package](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/processing/package-summary.html) to search using xpath into the resulting XML/HTML.

The XML parser that's built into Codename One isn't strict and should be able to parse most XML files without a problem. To fetch the file for parsing you can use the `ConnectionRequest` class, where you can also set the user agent.